# Regarding Chromium browser launch with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Could any team member provide valuable time to launch chromium browser by selenium C# programming language that will also remove SSL certification and unwanted pop up dialog with any URL

Thank you for giving valuable time in advance 
Thanks
Amit